# CSS height transition in presence of padding (not covered by existing answers)

Tags: css

[My question differs from the suggested duplicate because of the presence of padding in my animated div]

Trying to get a div to expand, without having fixed heights and with some padding. My css is below and I toggle `.closed` in and out using jquery.

```
.slide {
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: height 2s;
  transition: max-height 2s;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.closed {
  height: 0;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

The issue is that with the padding you can't hide the text to start with, and without a fixed height you don't get a transitioned css change. Can anyone help - hope I don't need to do more with javascript?

**Update** I've now got to:

```
.slide {
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: max-height 2s ease;
  max-height: 500px;
}

.closed {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

See [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcXJjpJY1iEy2v078W2F?p=preview). The problem now is the padding on closing. In the case above it transitions out, and if i limit the transition in .closed to `max-height` then there is a jarring effect as it collapses just as the animation starts.

Comment: You can't transition to `height:auto` in CSS..even JQuery can't do that natively...although there are plug-ins to add that functionality. You could try  transitioning `max-height` instead.

Comment: max height will work as long as you wrap the content in something.  That's the only thing you are missing: http://plnkr.co/edit/3caEykW27d7pgHOfT6Fp?p=preview.

It does however have an unsightly delay for close.

Comment: @Paulie_D definitely not a duplicate, this question is about padding.

Answer (score 6):

Hello I imagine that you have this fixed now as you posted a long time ago, but I just came across the same situation and made my own solution.

Basically I just created an empty div within the element that you are showing/hiding and applied the padding to that.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="padding-div">
          <li>menu-item</li>
          <li>another-menu-item</li>
          <li>yet-another-menu-item</li>
     </div>
</ul>


.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height:0;
    transition: max-height 0.7s ease-in;
    right: 0;
    top: 60px;
    width: 125px;
}

.padding-div {
    padding: 20px;

    /* Whatever you need to position everything correctly again eg.*/
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is partially in the updated answer and also partially in the updated plnkr link, but I overlooked that the plnkr link had updated code that's not in the post, and I instead used another answer's suggestion to use a wrapper `div`, so here's the alternate, updated answer:

To transition a div whose height comes from its content into a sliding open/closed motion using CSS, you should do the following:

- Use `max-height` to collapse the element because transitioning to `height: auto` doesn't work
- Use overflow hidden along with the transition so that the content is properly contained while the height changes
- If you have padding within the element, you'll notice collapsing the height doesn't fully collapse the element - because of this we should also remove padding when closed. Note: the same is also true for margin.
- Should only collapse padding/margin-top/bottom so that the content doesn't move horizontally on collapse since we're collapsing vertically. Flip this if you want to collapse horizontally via width instead.

1 final note (while a bit dated), if you're already using JQuery, you can use JQuery's `slideToggle` to accomplish this same functionality. In fact, it's doing almost the exact same CSS changes (shrinking height and vertical margin/padding with overflow hidden) only with JS rather than CSS transitions. You can see this for inspiration/memory if you inspect an element while it's toggle sliding via JQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").on("click", function() {
    console.log("click");
    $(".slide").toggleClass("closed");
  });
  
  $(".btn2").on("click", function() {
    $(".slide2").slideToggle(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.slide {
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: gold;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: padding-top 2s, padding-bottom 2s, margin-top 2s, margin-bottom 2s, max-height 2s;
  max-height: 1000px;
}

.closed {
  max-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slide2 {
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">Press Me</button>
<div class="slide closed">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas temporibus tempore cumque aut. Culpa voluptatibus laudantium laborum dolor quae. Assumenda, beatae, similique repudiandae adipisci ipsam quisquam veniam quaerat eveniet nobis.</div>
  <div>Laboriosam, ut, rerum, natus consequatur dolores nulla quaerat mollitia reiciendis harum vitae at rem architecto pariatur provident quam velit error numquam incidunt repellat nam temporibus magni ullam minima ducimus magnam.</div>
</div>
<p>Multiple things needed here to make this work:
  <ul>
    <li>For content with variable height (i.e. height: auto), use max-height instead since CSS transitions for height: auto don't work.</li>
    <li>Once the padding is added in, because we're only collapsing the height, the padding remains. On close, should remove the padding as well with padding: 0.</li>
    <li>Notice with padding: 0 now, it collapses entirely but there's a jarring effect where the content moves in/out from the corner. This is because on close, we're removing the vertical <i>and</i> the horizontal padding. The close is only vertical though so we really only need to remove the vertical padding and the horizontal padding can remain so instead use <code>padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0;</code></li>
    <li>Finally update transition property to transition the appropriate attributes - padding-top and padding-bottom or all if that works for you.</li>
  </ul>
</p>

<button class="btn2">With JQuery</button>
<div class="slide2" hidden>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas temporibus tempore cumque aut. Culpa voluptatibus laudantium laborum dolor quae. Assumenda, beatae, similique repudiandae adipisci ipsam quisquam veniam quaerat eveniet nobis.</div>
  <div>Laboriosam, ut, rerum, natus consequatur dolores nulla quaerat mollitia reiciendis harum vitae at rem architecto pariatur provident quam velit error numquam incidunt repellat nam temporibus magni ullam minima ducimus magnam.</div>
</div>
```